# Рекурсивный итератор

Tags: c#, рекурсия

Есть рекурсивная функция для индексации каталогов и файлов. Мне нужно создать иерархический вид файловой структуры. Я делаю итерацию переменной (пусть будет i) на каждом проходе рекурсивной функции. То есть, вглубь итерация проходит так, как надо. Но когда дело доходит до следующей папки, которая выше уровнем, итерация не делает "откат" до предыдущего состояния. Как можно избежать этого явления?
пример того, как нужно: 1-2-3-4-5-6-2-3-4-2-3 (цифры- идентификаторы узлов).
то, что получается: 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11

И, да, ЯП- C#.

Comment: код то будет?

Comment: по-моему, так тут проблема в логике реализации, а не в коде. В любой простейшей рекурсивной функции если поставить переменную-счетчик будет наблюдаться это явление.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private static void Inspect(string dir, int level)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", level, dir);
        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", level, file);
        }

        foreach (var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir))
        {
            Inspect(directory, level + 1);
        }
    }
```

например

Comment: переменная level будет увеличиваться постоянно. То есть, если Вы вернетесь в папку на уровень выше (когда не обнаружится больше каталогов), итерация не вернется на прежний уровень. Но это в идеале. у Вас же просто будет отслеживать порядковый номер папки в папке-родителе.

Comment: http://s58.radikal.ru/i161/1302/86/ffe30b13bb9a.png
УМВР

Comment: Ага. Неплохо. Сейчас, попробую еще раз реализовать.

Comment: @Tyler, внимание, код условный:

int i = 0; iter(i);
iter(int i) { if(i < 3) iter(i+1); print i; }

Вывод: 3210. То есть вызов iter(i+i) никак не меняет значение переменной i в вызываемой функции.